# Prove that function $f$ has a strict local maximum at point $a$ if $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be infinitely differentiable. Knowing that $$f'(a)=f''(a)=f'''(a)=f^{(4)}(a)=f^{(5)}(a)=0 \quad and \quad\; f^{(6)}(a)<0$$
prove that $f$ has a strict local maximum at point $a$.

Regarding this problem my idea is to use Taylors formula but I am not sure how to use it to complete the proof. If the problem is unclear, let me know as well. I did my best to translate it from Swedish to English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor's formula shows that
$f(x) = p_5(x)+ r_5(x)$, and the assumptions show that $p_5(x) = f(a)$.

The remainder can be written as $r_5(x) = {1 \over 6!} f^{(6)}(\xi) (x-a)^6$, where $\xi$ 
lies between $x,a$.

Since $f^{(6)}(a)<0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that for $\xi \in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ we have
$f^{(6)}(\xi)< {1 \over 2} f^{(6)}(a)$ (keep in mind the sign!).

Hence for $x \in  (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ we have $f(x) = p_5(x)+ r_5(x) = f(a) + {1 \over 6!} f^{(6)}(\xi) (x-a)^6 \le f(a) + {1 \over 2}{1 \over 6!} f^{(6)}(a) (x-a)^6$,
from which it follows that $a$ is strict local $\max$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f(a)=0$ then there is a continous function $g$ so that $f(x) = (x-a)\cdot g(x)$ for all $x$. This follows from noting that 
$$f(x)=\int_a^x f'(t)\ dt = \int_{0}^1(x-a) f'(t(x-a)+a)\ dt = (x-a)\int_0^1 f'(t(x-a)+a)dt$$
For your $f$ you will get by induction that:
$$f(x)-f(a) = (x-a)^6 g(x)$$
for some smooth $g$. This is basically Taylors formula. Anyway check that $f^{(6)}(a)= 6!\ g(a) < 0$ whence it is clear that $a$ is a local maximum of $f$.